# What happens internally when I make a web service call from silveright code?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am in to a project that uses Silverlight and am not quite clear on few things with SL.

I understand that SL downloads the xap on to the client browser and makes a lot of things easier that way. The aspx or html page loads SL plugin and downloads xap in browser. I have my web application deployed in IIS and have few WCF web services hosted on IIS (http) and also a few as windows services (net.tcp).

What about wcf service calls that I make from Silverlight code ? Since I can call WCF http or net.tcp based services directly from Silverlight code, it makes me wonder if the SL client is able to directly talk to the web services from browser (or) SL calls run to website which then makes the service calls ?

I am guessing am missing to understand some basics here. Please can someone explain what happens in this scenario in SL. Any links to some deeper understanding is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you run Fiddler and watch the traffic. Very educational. Usually easiest to use *WCF RIA services* with Silverlight, rather than plain WCF direct. Service calls are direct from browser/Silverlight (you don't actually care which). The website purely hosts both the services and the Silverlight webpage.

Comment: PS. The XAP file is just a renamed ZIP file. Feel free to rename and unpack one and see what gets downloaded to the browser.

Comment: @True - Thanks. I will try fiddler. I am trying to understand more in terms of the IIS worker process involvement w.r.to the webservice calls. I am assuming if the web service is hosted in IIS, then SL calls to the web service will go through the IIS worker process ? And when a service is hosted as standalone, say in a window service, SL would not use anything in IIS ? This is where I am slightly confused.

Comment: Personally I have not had to connect to a self-hosted service from Silverlight (I did not even know it could do that). I always used WCF RIA service for the convenience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight can communicate directly with about anything in the local or external network when tcp is the underlying protocol, bar some security restrictions.

When you communicate with a local WCF Service based on tcp, for example, you still need the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` be served by http on the save host - or run Silverlight with elevated permissions.

For http, Silverlight can use both ask the browser to make a request or make a request directly (I'm not sure which is used for wcf), tcp will always be done from the plugin directly.

The Silverlight application has to be hosted by a website, but the website doesn't need to do anything beyond that for Silverlight to work, or for it to access a WCF Services. You can host a Silverlight app as purely static files.

Comment: Thanks John. I am tempted to accept. So does that mean if I host a tcp service then I need to open up ports 4503-4535 to make the SL app communicate with the tcp service. I am thinking definitely not ideal for an external facing web app.

Comment: @Mani Not if the client (ie Silverlight) initiates the connection, because home routers generally deal with such cases. You have to expect this to make problems in corporate environments, where port 80 is often the only thing that's allowed reliably. (This isn't specific to Silverlight though.) If you're the author of the service and you're looking for bi-directional communication (the only case I know in which I would be motivated to chose raw tcp over http if I'm the author of both endpoints), you might want to consider signalr, a newer development that isn't wcf at all.